# How can I return value from completion block to use it in other viewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to retrieve a value from `queryCompletionBlock` and sent it to another `viewController`.

Here is my code:

```
func KcalCloudKitData() {
    publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase
    allRecords = []
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Kcal", predicate: predicate)
    query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "KcalCoef", ascending: true)]
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = {(record: CKRecord) in
        self.allRecords.append(record)
    }

    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = {cursor, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed loading data from iCloud")
            //print(error?.localizedFailureReason)
        } else {

            for value in self.allRecords {
                self.kcalUnitValid.append(value.object(forKey: "KcalValidUnit") as! [String])
            }
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AppLoaded", sender: nil)
        }
    }
    print(self.kcalUnitValid)
    publicDatabase?.add(queryOperation)
}
```

When i print using code `print(self.kcalUnitValid)` outside the completion block this obtains an empty table. Any solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`queryCompletionBlock` is executed asynchronously so by the time `print(self.kcalUnitValid)` is called `queryCompletionBlock` **wouldn't** have finished its execution yet, in other words, the order in how execution happens is like below sequentially:

- 1.- `queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock(..)` **is called**
- 2.- `print(self.kcalUnitValid)` **is called** `// prints empty`
- 3.- after some seconds the result of `queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock(..)` **is returned**

---

## Code

What you could do it probably is this:

```
func KcalCloudKitData() {
  // .. code omitted
  queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = {cursor, error in
    if error != nil {
      // .. code omitted
    } else {
      for value in self.allRecords {
        self.kcalUnitValid.append(value.object(forKey: "KcalValidUnit") as! [String])
      }

      // Segue to another ViewController
      // And also sending kcalUnitValid
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AppLoaded", sender: self.kcalUnitValid)
    }
  }
  // .. code omitted
}

// Actually in this method is when you decide 
// what data you are going to send to the AnotherViewController
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "AppLoaded" {
    let anotherViewController = segue.destination as! AnotherViewController
    anotherViewController.kcalUnitValid = sender as! Array<[String]>
  }
}
```

## Resources:

[Watch this video explaning async programming in Swift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzFQXE6Y44M)

Comment: Thanks Wilson for your help. It worked. It was the best solution.

Comment: glad it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

It is because the completion **closure** (block is term for Objective-C) was called after the task was finished: e.g. your

```
self.kcalUnitValid.append(...)
```

task is done later than the line

```
print(self.kcalUnitValid)
```

regardless it stands before the print code in the controller.

Completion handler is fired, when the queryOperation is ready to do it. And this is supposed to happen later than your print.

So you should e.g. print that value within the closure.

```
queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = {cursor, error in
    ...
        self.kcalUnitValid.append(value.object(forKey: "KcalValidUnit") as! [String])

    print(self.kcalUnitValid)
    ...
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: Thanks pedrouan for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can not return value from completion block so use another completion block(as parameter of method), and call it when your task is completed something like,

```
 func hardProcessingWithString(input: String, completion: (result: String) -> Void) {
...
completion("we finished!")
}
```

and you can use it like,

```
hardProcessingWithString("commands") {
(result: String) in
print("got back: \(result)")
}
```

So write a function that can call it's own completion handler on completion of task that you want to perform.

Reference :

https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/

https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/

Comment: Thanks Lion for your help